# Query base type documents

Tags: .net, ravendb

I have a `BaseEntity` and a set of derived entities: `DerivedEntity1`, `DerivedEntity2`, etc.. Every derived document is stored to its collection. Is there any way to retrieve all documents which are derived from base type? Something like that:

```
var baseEntities = documentSession.Query<BaseEntity>().ToList();
```

I have found some ways but they require to know all derived entities types. It doesn't suite me as in my case these types are generated kind of dynamically.

Answer (score 3):

The docs discuss this issue, see here:
http://ravendb.net/docs/client-api/querying/polymorphism

Comment: The FindTypeTagName approach suits me well but is there any way to retrieve documents of specific type (e. g. DerivedEntity1) after applying FindTypeTagName which maps all derived entities to base entity collection?